# Upload to AWS S3 with createPresignedPost (nextjs api)-- How to know if successfully uploaded?

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, aws-sdk

I upload the file using aws-sdk createPresignedPost. I wanted to know how to check if its successfully uploaded. Is there a callback response if the file is already in S3 Bucket?

This is the snipped of the code:

```
     const post = s3.createPresignedPost({
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
        Fields: {
            "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
            "Content-Disposition": `inline; filename="${req.query.file}"`,
            key: req.query.file,
        },
        Expires: 60, // seconds
        Conditions: [
            ["content-length-range", 0, 5048576], // up to 1 MB
        ],
    });

    if (post) {
        console.log("Post data --->", post);
        res.status(200).json({ post });
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to check? You want to check if the one requesting the presigned url then actually used it to put data into the bucket? No there is no callback other than hooking up bucket notification in S3, listening for new objects and then trying to correlate that with the first request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @luk2302. But is there a callback for upload progress instead?